# Where do I need place public methods in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have `run` method where I implemented two *public* methods: `pxH` and `phW` that return screen width and height in pixels (converted from %).

```
app.run(function(){

   var calcPixels = function(size, valueInPersent){
        return ( size * valueInPersent / 100 ) + 'px';
    };

    $rootScope.pxH = function(valueInPersent){            
        return calcPixels(window.innerHeight, valueInPersent);
    };

    $rootScope.pxW = function(valueInPersent){
        return calcPixels( window.innerWidth, valueInPersent );
    };

});
```

The usage is from HTML over all my project:

```
<div class="row" ng-style="{'height': pxH(21.7)}"></div>
```

I have about 20 HTML files and I use these methods in all of them.

Do I need to leave methods `pxH` and `phW` under `$rootScope` or there is more proper way to place them?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory:

```
app.factory('calc', function() {
    return {
       calcPixels: function (size, valueInPersent){
          return ( size * valueInPersent / 100 ) + 'px';
       },

       pxH: function (valueInPersent){            
           return calcPixels(window.innerHeight, valueInPersent);
       },

       pxW: function(valueInPersent){
           return calcPixels( window.innerWidth, valueInPersent );
       }
   }
});
```

Then in your controller, inject the service:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, calc) {
      $scope.calcPixels = calc.calcPixels;
      etc...
});
```

Comment: I would recommend use rather `controller('myController', ['$scope','calc', function($scope, calc) {...}])` since this way of linking seems more robust to me

Comment: Also naming the factory something a bit more describing that just 'calc'.

Comment: The problem that all my controllers (!10-15) must use this factory